# Using 'await' but still receiving this error: A second operation started... Use 'await' to ensure that

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asynchronous, owin

When the user session ends, a popup shows up in my application and when the user clicks "Stay in the system", the RefreshTheUserSession action of the Account controller is evoked.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshTheUserSession(string UserId)//this will be called from the ajax timeout
{
      AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
      var myuser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId);

      if (myuser != null)
      {
          await SignInManager.SignInAsync(myuser, false, false);
      }

        return null;
 }
```

Here is the AuthenticationManager property of the Account controller that comes by default by MVC application.

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
 {
     get
     {
         return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
     }
 }
```

However, when the `RefreshTheUserSession` action is executed, I receive the following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

It recommends me to use `await` and I am using `await`. I have no idea why this is happening. Any ideas or leads?

Comment: You realise that now anyone can call this action method and log in as an user they choose?

Comment: @DavidG thanks for the heads up, this app is just for a small study.

Comment: It'll looks fine except for returning null. Why null? Since it's an Ajax call, I'd return JsonResult to indicate 200 instead.

Comment: @EddiePaz an exception is raised before it returns a value. this is my issue. however, I will listen to you and return a jsonresult.

Comment: How about instead of SignInManager, use:

var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);